# Issue with saving classifier as a pickle file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried saving my Multinomial Naive Bayes classifier as a `.pkl` file but encountered an error.

I tried

```
import pickle

with open(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\clf.pkl','rb') as f:
    pickle.dump(mnb,f) 
#mnb is the MultinomialNB classifier
```

I am getting the error as

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\clf.pkl'
```

Do I need to create a file first somewhere?

Comment: You are opening `rb` that is for reading

Comment: Why are you trying to read a file (`rb` mode) when you want to write to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to save it, then open it in `'wb'` write mode instead of `'rb'` read mode as following:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\clf.pkl','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(mnb,f)
```

> In write mode, it will automatically create a file if not present!

It will solve your problem. Hope, it helps.

Comment: Damn it, how could I miss that. Thanks a lot. :)